# Hibernate and Spring - Database tables not being automatically created

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been trying to use Spring and Hibernate together. At the moment I am trying to make Hibernate create the tables automatically. According to the documentation and examples I have found online, this should be achievable by setting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create`, `create-drop` or `update`. For some reason this is not working. Below is where I am declaring my beans (in `\WEB-INF\dispatcher-servlet.xml`):

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_SHOP" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.crimsonwing.dto.UserDTO</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

This is how I am declaring my DTO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "EMAIL", "UID" }))
public class UserDTO implements Serializable
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Validation Annotation
@Size(min = 8, max = 30, message = "User name must be between 8 and 30 characters long.")
// Database Anotation
@Column(name = "NAME", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

// Validation Annotation
@NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
@Min(1)
@Max(99)
// Database Anotation
@Column(name = "AGE", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
private int age;

// Validation Annotation
@UniqueEmail
@Email(message = "Email is incorrect format.")
@NotEmpty(message = "Email cannot be left empty")
// Database Anotation
@Column(name = "EMAIL", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

// Database Anotation
@Id
@Column(name = "UID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue()
private String userUID;

public UserDTO(String name, int age, String email)
{
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
}

public UserDTO()
{
    /* WILL BE USED BY HIBERNATE */
}

...
```

And this is how I am trying to access the database:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements IUserDAO
{
    @Resource
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Override
    public bbolean userExists(String userEmail)
    {
        UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
        user.setEmail(userEmail);

        DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(user.getClass());

        return (this.hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria).size() > ) ? true : false;
    }
...
```

Anyone can point me out in the right direction? Is there a missing setting or something I did wrong? I am using MySQL version `5.1.58-1ubuntu1` on an Ubuntu x64 platform with spring 3.1 and hibernate 3.6.10.

Thanks.

EDIT: Stacktrace added for completeness:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'MY_SHOP.USER' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1039)
    at com.crimsonwing.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.userExists(UserDAOImpl.java:36)
    at com.crimsonwing.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.userExists(UserServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.crimsonwing.facades.impl.UserFacadeImpl.userExists(UserFacadeImpl.java:34)
    at com.crimsonwing.validator.uniqueemail.impl.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:26)
    at com.crimsonwing.validator.uniqueemail.impl.UniqueEmailValidator.isValid(UniqueEmailValidator.java:1)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:139)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:722)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Edit:

As per parasietje's suggestion, this is the resulting HQL:
`Hibernate: select this_.UID as UID2_0_, this_.AGE as AGE2_0_, this_.EMAIL as EMAIL2_0_, this_.NAME as NAME2_0_ from USER this_`

I do not get any other HQL. If I remember correctly, when the table is being created you also get to see the resulting HQL statement, which is not what is happening in this case.

Comment: you misspelled "localhost"...

Comment: @pap: Yes I know, unfortunately that is a mistake I made while pasting the code. I have made the changes updated the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Try by writing a method that will insert the data?That might help us debug more.

Comment: Can you add the property hibernate.show_sql=true so Hibernate shows all SQL?

Comment: @ManuPK: I am using a custom validator to see if a user with the same ID exists. When I run the query, I get an error saying that the table cannot be found, as shown in my original question.

Comment: @parasietje: I have added the property and have modified my answer. I shall be looking forward for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Does the schema `MY_SHOP` actually exists, my understanding is Hibernate is not gonna create a schema , it will just create class under an existing schema.

So try creating the schema if not and also try adding the schema in the table annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", , schema="MY_SHOP", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "EMAIL", "UID" }))
public class UserDTO implements Serializable
{
```